# Use injected service from JS code to static Blazor method

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an app that uses a jQuery lib to show 'confirmation' dialogs.

When a user clicks 'OK' or 'Cancel' on the dialog, then first a callback is made to my Javascript code. From there I do a call to a Blazor method, based on the decision the user made.

This all looks something like this:

My js code:

```
$('.alert-yesno).on('click', function() {
    // For simplicity I immediately call the Blazor method
    DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('[Assembly name]', 'DoSomething')
                            .then(data => {
                                // do something...
                            });
});
```

Blazor page:

```
@inject MyService MyService

<button class="alert-yesno">Show dialog</button>

@code
{
    [JSInvokable]
    public static async Task DoSomething()
    {
        // How to use the non static MyService here...?
    }
}
```

This all works fine. The Javascript part calls my Blazor method. But how can I use `MyService` from there? This is injected into the page. Which is good, because it makes use of dependency injection.

I don't want to create a `new` instance everytime from within the `static` method, because that way I loose all the auto injected dependencies.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0#instance-method-call for a more complete example, but you can pass a reference to the the .net instance to the javascript code by calling

```
DotNetObjectReference.Create(myInstance);
```

Then the javascript code can call the instance method on that object. Since the component (and thus the service which is injected into it) has a potentially different lifespan than the jquery click handler, this might cause some other issues, but the link above should be a good starting point.